Neo4j Cypher conversion to Gremlin query
We are trying to convert the Neo4j cypher query into a Gremlin query, but we are stuck on some extract methods in the cypher query that need to be converted into the Gremlin query.
The cypher query that we are trying to convert is as follows:
MATCH (from: `Person` {title: "John"}), (to: `Location` {title: "New York City"})
MATCH p = (from)-[rel*..5]->(to)
RETURN extract(x IN nodes(p) | x.title) as title,
            extract(i IN relationships(p)| type(i)) as relation,
            extract(j IN nodes(p) | j.nt) as node,
            length(p) as len,
            extract(x IN nodes(p) | x) as node_data,
            extract (i in nodes(p)| id(i)) as id,
            extract(i IN relationships(p)| id(i)) as rel_id,
            extract(rel IN relationships(p) | id(startNode(rel))) as start,
            extract(rel IN relationships(p) | id(endNode(rel))) as end

Output of the above query as follow:
[
  {
    "title": ["John", "new york city"],  // 'title' is property of the vertices
    "relation": ["WORKIGN_AT"],          // Edge label between 'person' and 'location'
    "node": ["Person", "Location"],      // List of labels
    "len": 1,                            // Node hop between two node label
    "node_data": [                       // List of node property data (valueMap())
      {
        "Employee_Status": "Active",
        "FT_or_PT": "Full Time",
        "title": "john"
      },
      {
        "Office_Type": "Headquarters",
        "Mailing_Code": 10022,
        "ISO_Alpha_Two_Country_Code": "US",
        "City": "New York",
        "title": "New York City",
        "Display": "New York City",
        "Name": "New York City"
      }
    ],
    "id": [5432,5125],                     // List of node id in the hopes
    "rel_id": [17409],                     // list of edge id in the hopes 
    "start": [5432],                       // id of from nodes in the hopes
    "end": [5125]                          // id of to nodes in the l
  }
]


I'm looking for a Gremlin query that can effectively replace the extract method for Neo4j and produce the same output. Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Chypre? Cypher?

See https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#match-step and you can transform each cyper extraction into a match step argument.

@HadoopMarc, thank you for your response. I already have this documentation, but I am still experiencing issues in obtaining the expected output.
